# npm error when Installing hyperledger Hurley

Tags: node.js, npm, hyperledger, hurley

Trying to install Hyperledger Hurley on ubuntu 18.04 using this command :
sudo npm install -g @worldsibu/hurley --unsafe-perm=true

New ubuntu 18.04 vm with nothing related Hyperledger installed on it. (Is it the issue ??)

I get the following error msg :

gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at getNotFoundError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5

Error from th npm log file :

18744 verbose stack Error: @ampretia/x509@0.4.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild
18744 verbose stack Exit status 1
18744 verbose stack
at EventEmitter. (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:326:16)
18744 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:209:13)
node-gyp rebuild

Did anybody saw something like that already ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Considering that you have tried all the possible answers available. Try this, In your package-lock.json, comment node-gyp in node-sass object.Then Try npm install.

Comment: @Sagar Chaudhary : Could you tell me where this file 'package-lock' should be located ? Can found more than one on my system ... Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed.
Replace nodejs v12 by nodejs v8.x

Configure npm to run without sudo rights with :

```
$ npm config set prefix "~/.npm-global"

$ nano .profile
...
# NPM
 export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
$ source .profile
```

and than you can install hurley succesfully with:

```
npm install -g @worldsibu/hurley
```

without sudo and without "--unsafe-perm=true"